# Active directory integration with python

Tags: python, active-directory

I am trying to connect to active directory to fetch list of users in python. I am new to python and active directory. I tried running code after seeing some tutorials.

How to fetch list of users.

Example of code:

```
def ldap_ActiveDirectory():
 user = 'xxx'
 password = ''xxxx'
 server = ldap.Server("LDAP://xxxxxx")
 connection = ldap.Connection(server, user=user, password=password)
 connection.bind()

ldap_result_id = connection.search(
        search_base='cn=users,dc=ms,dc=ds,dc=uhc,dc=com',
        search_filter='(sAMAccountType=805306368)',
        search_scope='SUBTREE',
        attributes='*'
)
```

I have done  pip install python-ldap
and pip install ldap  both. What is the best way to connect to active directory from python and fetch users. I want to display the list of users in autocomplete box. ldap_result_id gives me false. How to fetch results from active directory?

Thanks

Comment: Have you done 'Import ldap' in the beginning of your code?

Comment: Hi yes.. I was able to create connection..but now how to fetch list of users..

Comment: Could you show me the error that you are getting?

Comment: Could you show your entire code and the entire error that you get?

Comment: This is very confusing. I suggest that you  modify your question and use code blocks to show both your input and output.